# implement/show styled RSS Feed in PHP (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I have an amazon link

```
http://www.amazon.de/rss/new-releases/videogames/
```

I'd like to have it shown on a place of my choice. I have an external php file in which the rss feed should show up as kind of list. Has somebody an idea of getting this working without plugin?

Thanks a lot folks!

AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code have to be pasted wherever you want to display the feed.

Don't forget to update the feed url on line 3. Number of items to be displayed can be defined on line 6.

```
<?php
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php');
$feed = 'http://www.amazon.de/rss/new-releases/videogames/';
$rss = fetch_feed($feed);
if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) :
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(3);
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
    if ($rss_items):
        echo "<ul>\n";
        foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) :
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="' . $item->get_permalink() . '">' . $item->get_title() . "</a>\n";
            echo '<p>' . $item->get_description() . "</li>\n";
        endforeach;
        echo "</ul>\n";
    endif;
endif;
?>
```

**Source:** http://wprecipes.com

P.S. don't forget that there is a dedicated SE for Wordpress at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is this cached? Wouldn't this bring his blog down (just specific page) if there is any network issue?

Comment: Hi Vince, Thank you for the super fast reply. I thought, this could be also something outside of wordpress and so I was afraid of asking a general question in the "wordpress.stackexchange.com" section. What is about the "/rss.php" - i'm getting an error, that theres something wrong: "include_once() [function.include-once]: Unable to find the wrapper "ABSPATHWPINChttp" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?"

Comment: It's not cached and no it wouldn't bring the blog down if there is a network issue, it simply wouldn't show the feed.

Comment: Could you paste the code as you've added it on to your site as I've tested it on my WP install and it seems to be working fine with the amazon feed.

Comment: ok - I have the problem, that no feed at all is shown, also when I use "?feed=rss2", etc. - I am working on the website behind a htaccess protection, maybe this has something to do. Or do I need to activate feed at all in the functions.php?

Comment: I've just tried it with the code that I've updated above in a fresh WP install at http://www.optronicsnet.com/imagedatabase/ and it seems to be showing up OK (obviously no formatting has been applied).

Comment: ok thank you a lot. It says "no such file "rss.php" in my folder...I will work with your code! many thanks!!!

Comment: Hi Vince, could you be so kind and paste the content of the "rss.php" - somehow in my version of wordpress it is not included - even in the latest wordpresspackage it's not inlcuded....thank you!

Comment: it should be in the wp-includes folder?

Comment: Hi Vince, your code works, I found out the problem and posted it on the wordpress stackexchange :http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58860/problems-with-jquery-external-rss-feed-integration